# ups-worldship autoimport xml signature required not working but the label prints

Tags: xml, auto-import, ups-worldship

Does anyone have an example of adult signature required for worldship ups xml autoimport?  I get the label to print but the package gets left on the porch no signature.

```
    <element type = "Signature-AdultSignatureRequired" minOccurs = "0" maxOccurs = "1"/>
    <element type = "SignatureRequired" minOccurs = "0" maxOccurs = "1"/>
    <element type = "AdultSignatureRequired" minOccurs = "0" maxOccurs = "1"/>
    <element type = "AdultSignatureRequired" minOccurs = "0" maxOccurs = "1"/>
<ElementType name = "SignatureRequired" content = "textOnly" dt:type = "string" model = "closed" wsi:maxLength = "1" wsi:datatype = "boolean"/>
<ElementType name = "AdultSignatureRequired" content = "textOnly" dt:type = "string" model = "closed" wsi:maxLength = "1" wsi:datatype = "boolean"/>
<ElementType name = "Signature-AdultSignatureRequired" content = "textOnly" dt:type = "string" model = "closed" wsi:maxLength = "2"/>
```

Comment: You may have an authentication issue.  See https://developer.ups.com/api/reference?loc=en_US#operation/Locator

Comment: Im using worldship auto import xml.  But evetually I'll get to the oath stuff.  Thanks for the comment. @jdweng

Comment: It is in appendix 1.  See : https://developer.ups.com/api/reference?loc=en_US#operation/Rate

Comment: I'm using auto xml import and this is api documentation.   I create a xml file and the world ship program loads it from the disk drive.   Thanks again for trying to help @jdweng.

Comment: I found the php equivalent that may help ; https://docs.rocketship.it/php/1-0/signature-options.html

Comment: I got the signature required to work by adding a signature services node<SignatureServices<AdultSignatureRequired>1</AdultSignatureRequired</SignatureServices>

Comment: I wish I could use a thrid party api that integrates with several shippers.  But  unfortunately management didn't agree.  Thanks again @jdweng